# OpenAl mp3 loop not working

Tags: c++, audio, mp3, openal

I'm trying to play sound in **c++** project using **OpenAl**. I want to play a music track that will loop. When the file is a **.wav** or **.mp3** at **320 kbps** this **works just fine**. But when trying with a **.mp3** at **32 kbps** it shall **not loop**.

Another thing is that, if I set the **AL_LOOPING** flag to true when using the .mp3 it will start for 1 second and then restart the track. The flag works just fine when playing a .wav

My code is

```
alGenSources(1, &__alSource);
openAlResult = alGetError();
if (openAlResult != AL_NO_ERROR)
{
    return ConvertError(openAlResult);
}

alSourcef (__alSource, AL_PITCH, 1.0);
alSourcef (__alSource, AL_GAIN, 1.0);
alSource3f(__alSource, AL_POSITION, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
alSource3f(__alSource, AL_VELOCITY, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
alSource3f(__alSource, AL_DIRECTION, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
alSourcef(__alSource, AL_ROLLOFF_FACTOR, 0.0);
alSourcei(__alSource, AL_SOURCE_RELATIVE, AL_TRUE);
// only works for WAV
alSourcei(__alSource, AL_LOOPING, AL_TRUE);

openAlResult = alGetError();

if (openAlResult != AL_NO_ERROR)
{
    return ConvertError(openAlResult);
}
```

Any ideas regarding the .mp3 at 32 kbps format or way it will not loop ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have to call the alSourcePlay(__alSource); after you set the loop.

```
alGenSources(1, &__alSource);
```

```html
alGenSources(1, &__alSource);
openAlResult = alGetError();

if (openAlResult != AL_NO_ERROR) {
    return ConvertError(openAlResult);
}

alSourcef (__alSource, AL_PITCH, 1.0);
alSourcef (__alSource, AL_GAIN, 1.0);
alSource3f(__alSource, AL_POSITION, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
alSource3f(__alSource, AL_VELOCITY, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
alSource3f(__alSource, AL_DIRECTION, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
alSourcef(__alSource, AL_ROLLOFF_FACTOR, 0.0);
alSourcei(__alSource, AL_SOURCE_RELATIVE, AL_TRUE);
// only works for WAV
alSourcei(__alSource, AL_LOOPING, AL_TRUE);
alSourcePlay(__alSource);

openAlResult = alGetError();

if (openAlResult != AL_NO_ERROR) {
    return ConvertError(openAlResult);
}
```